# Mongodb y fechas

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

tengo un problema, cuando guardo una fecha, se guarda así:

**2018-12-04T00:00:00.000Z**

y yo quisiera que la hora sea las 23:00 no las 00:00

**2018-12-04T23:00:00.000Z**

---

Es una api, con express y node

```
function SaveOfferDay(req, res){
var update = req.body;
var id = req.params.id;



Offer.update(   {"_id": id},{"$addToSet": {"date": {"day" : new Date("2018-12-04"),}}}, (err, offerUpdated) => {
if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});
return res.status(200).send({offer: offerUpdated});

});
}
```

Comment: Hola my crazy. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio. Las preguntas han de tener más informacion sobre el codigo que estás usando y un ejemplo para reproducir tu problema. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: My crazy, lee el [tour] como te indiqué. Asi sabrás que las preguntas han de editarse, y no crear "respuestas"  que no lo son para añadir informacion. Un saludo

Comment: "Manualmente si se puede" pero si esa fecha fuese una variable. no puedo decirle que la guarde en esa hora

Comment: antes de guardarla formateala, o envianos el cfodigo que recibes al guardar

Comment: La idea es que siempre lo guarde a las 11pm? Que lo guarde con una hora menos? Que lo ajuste de acuerdo a algún criterio? La pregunta no es nada clara.

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que todas las consultas que se van a realizar tendrá un formato de fecha de entrada 'YYYY-MM-DD', entonces lo que se pretende es añadir la hora a '23:00:00', ¿verdad?. En tal caso, para solucionar tu problema te invito a que le eches un vistazo al modulo de [`npm momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/docs/) donde podrás trabajar con las fechas de forma cómoda y sencilla.

Para tu caso, te muestro un ejemplo:

```
const moment = require('moment')

let test = "2018-12-04"

if(moment(test,'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid()){

   let fecha = moment(test).hour(23 + 1).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(000)

   console.log(test.toDate()) // => 2018-12-04T23:00:00.000Z

   Offer.update({ "_id": id }, { "$addToSet": { "date": { "day": test.toDate() } } })

} else {
console.log("Formato de fecha errónea (YYYY-MM-DD)")
}
```

Espero que sea de tu ayuda.

Saludos